# How are decisions taken in the European Council?

Tags: european-union, european-council

The European Council sets the impetus of the EU.

Treaty change is made here too.

How are decisions taken in the European Council?

Is it unanimity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the decision being made.

Most decisions are made by consensus.  If a vote is required by the treaties, then the decision will be made either by Qualified Majority (16 states representing 65% of the population), or unanimously, depending on what the treaties require for the particular decision.

[Source: European Union](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/european-council/)